# ASP.NET URL Navigation

Tags: asp.net

I have asp.net button and on it's button click I am redirecting it using

```
Response.Redirect ("SomeURL.aspx");
```

I am not passing anything to SomeURL.aspx. Can this be achieved without a roundtrip to the server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use an html anchor tag. This is the simplest approach and probably the best since anchors are the proper control to allow navigation.

```
<a href="SomeUrl.aspx">My link</a>
```

If you still want to use the asp.net button you could do something like this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton"
  OnClientClick="window.location.href='SomeURL.aspx'; return false;"
  Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - based on `Javascript Navigate`

```
window.navigate("SomeURL.aspx");
```

Sample

```
 <input type="button" value="Navigate to SomeURL" onclick="funcNavigate();"> 

  <script language="JavaScript">
  function funcNavigate() {
  window.navigate("SomeURL.aspx");
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be achieved without a roundtrip to the server?

Not using code behind.

However, you could wire up a client side click handler or use a hyperlink to accomplish the same thing.

```
<button onclick="window.location='SomeURL.aspx'; return false;">Some URL</a>
```

or

```
<a href="SomeURL.aspx">Some URL</a>
```

The hyperlink is the simplest answer.